# Как проверить, пишется ли что-либо?

Tags: python, python-3.x

недавно сделал программу, чтобы открывать приложение нажатием клавиши, и мне надо проверять, не пишется ли что-нибудь на данный момент в другом приложение ничего не вводилось, чтобы при, скажем, наборе текста в другом приложении, не открылось Visual Studio. Информации в интернете никакой не нашел

```
import subprocess
import keyboard
import time
time.sleep(1)
while True:
    keyboard.wait("v")
    subprocess.run(r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe")
```

Comment: Скорее всего это невозможно. Нельзя просто так взять и залезть в произвольное приложение и узнать, как именно оно обрабатывает нажатия — пишет или делает что-то другое

Comment: Спасибо, тогда по другому  сделаю